# Is it possible to add javascript to template parts

Tags: javascript, block-editor

Is it possible to add javascript to a template part, specifically I would like to add alpine.js to a template part. Any time I add a `x-data="menuOpen"` or even a data attribute I get `This block contains unexpected or invalid content`

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like your question is not about adding JavaScript to template parts, but is actually about adding a custom HTML attribute to a block. Is that accurate?

Comment: I should have phrased it a bit more broadly. Custom attributes are the most important piece but their are also things like `:class = "something" ? "this" : "that";` that I would like to add. From discussions on the wordpress plugin side it doesn't look like it's going to possible. I think Lovor's answer is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supposed to work (and it does not work) in a way you wanted. I guess you are talking about new FSE template parts (.hmtl), and not legacy (.php) template parts. You can only add HTML and blocks to .html template parts and javascript is enqueued as a part of a block. Alternatively, you can check in a functions.php if certain page/post/template/block is loaded and then enqueue javascript you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what I've gathered I will most likely need to create a custom block and add it to my header template part to achieve what I need. Your answer is accurate though.

Comment: You can also use `enqueue_block_assets` hook and check inside (php) `if has_block('namespace/your-block') wp_enqueue_script(...);`. However, if you need to create custom block for other things, adding script to `viewScript` in `block.json` is the most elegant solution.